# SonarQube not using `sonar.sources`

Tags: sonarqube

I have a `sonar-project.properties` file in the root of my project:

```
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=customers.embrace.sonarcloud.io
sonar.projectName=embracesbs
sonar.sources=/packages/web/bases/social
```

And a task to run `Run Code Analysis` in my build pipeline.

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: d:\a\_tasks\SonarCloudAnalyze_**********\1.9.0\sonar-scanner\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: d:\a\1\s\sonar-project.properties
```

When the analysis starts it states:

```
INFO: Found 16 tsconfig.json file(s): [D:\a\1\s\cypress\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\account\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\customercard\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\files\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\graphql\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\tasks\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\translations\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\web\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\common\widgets\src\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\web\apps\suite\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\web\bases\customers\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\web\bases\knowledge\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\web\bases\onboarding\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\web\bases\property\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\packages\web\bases\social\tsconfig.json, D:\a\1\s\tsconfig.json]
INFO: 1034 source files to be analyzed
```

I expected the analysis would only be done on the `/packages/web/bases/social` folder.

Comment: You may need a relative path, I'm not certain how it will work with Windows paths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause, but `sonar.sources` should use relative paths:

```
sonar.sources=packages/web/bases/social
```

Answer (score 0):

sonar.sources expect relative paths or use sonar.sources = .
 it will solve the issue .